# Checkbox array values

Tags: javascript

The values of the checkboxes are not getting stored. When i alert the values in place of selected += elements[i].value + "\n"; i am getting the values.

```
<script>

function whichIsChecked(){
   var selected = "";
   var elements = document.getElementsByName("colors[]");
   for(var i=0; i<=elements.length; i++){
       if(elements[i].checked){
          //alert(elements[i].value) // values are displayed
      selected += elements[i].value + "\n";
   }
   }    
  alert(selected); // not storing
}
</script>


<form method="post" action="">
  <input type="checkbox" name="colors[]" value="red">
  <input type="checkbox" name="colors[]" value="blue">
  <input type="checkbox" name="colors[]" value="green">

  <input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="whichIsChecked()">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `for` loop is going too far and causing a TypeError because elements[3] doesn't exist.  Change `<=` to be `<`.

Comment: +1. @karthik_spain the first step in debugging is always to check the error that your code is giving you – in this case open developer tools in Chrome or Firebug in Firefox and you'll see this error.

Comment: @CharlieS i am already using webdeveloper tool in firefox, which gave me TypeError. Wonder if error message would have been more meaningful like "out of range" or something similar to it.